# Example of a supplemented chief factor of a group

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, quotient-group

Let $H/K$ is a chief factor of a group $G$. We say $H/K$ is a supplemented chief factor of $G$ if there exists a proper subgroup $M$ of $G$ such that $G=MH$ and $K\leq H\cap M$ and $M$ is called supplement of $H/K$ in $G$. Can you give an example of a supplemented chief factor of a group? I want to understand it illustratively.

Comment: The simplest example with everything nontrivial is $G=C_2^3$, $K=C_2$, $H=C_2^2$. You can choose $M \cong C_2^2$ with $K = H \cap M$.

Comment: Okay. So, in this example $M$ will be $C_{2}$?

Comment: No. I said what $M$ is.

Comment: Yes. I checked, $M$ can't be isomorphic to $C_{2}$. In this case, i took $G=\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times\mathbb{ Z}_{2}\times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ . $K=<(0,1,0)>$, $H=<(0,1,0),(0,0,1)>$ and $M=<(1,0,1),(0,1,0)>$ then $G=MH$ and $K=H\cap M$. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many examples and I am not sure which one would be best to illustrate this concept. Anyway, my choice is the quaternion group of order $8$. The subgroup lattice of that group looks like this:

[image]

The blue dot is the trivial subgroup and the top one is the whole of $Q_8$. The three subgroups directly below it are the maximal subgroups of $Q_8$, all cyclic and of order $4$. The sole dot above the blue one is the Frattini subgroup of $Q_8$ and also its centre.

Now take as $K$ this subgroup, i.e. $K=\Phi(Q_8)$ and as $H$ any of the three maximal subgroups. Then $H/K$ is clearly a chief factor of $Q_8$ and it is easy  to see that any maximal subgroup other than the $H$ you chose is a supplement for $H$, i.e. it is the $M$ you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks you. In this example, if we take $M$ any other maximal subgroup than $H$. Then we have $H\cap M=K$. So, we can say $H/K$ is a complemented chief factor, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.